# Migrating to flatpak versions of apps

Tags: 19.04, flatpak

I'm considering moving a number of the programs I use to flatpak versions to have updated versions more quickly.

I tried with Libreoffice and I realised that it didn't inherit any configuration of the normal libreoffice that came with the Ubuntu installation.

Do flatpak apps keep their profiles in different folders that the standard folders like `~/.config`?

If they do, is it possible to somehow use or copy the profile of the normal app with the flatpak edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, they have different path but same organization, from freedesktop standards

  ```
  XDG_CONFIG_HOME   User-specific configuration files  ~/.var/app/<app-id>/config
  XDG_DATA_HOME     User-specific data                 ~/.var/app/<app-id>/data
  XDG_CACHE_HOME    Non-essential user-specific data   ~/.var/app/<app-id>/cache
  ```

  **Reference:** [Flatpak: Requirements & Conventions](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/conventions.html#xdg-base-directories)
- Yes with some degree, Issues may raise due to broken compatibly between versions. Manual editing may be needed to fix paths if store within config files, ...